# Очищать массив static после выполнения функции-рекурсии

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, static

Здравствуйте! Нашел в интернете такую рекурсивную функцию-генератор анкоров. Вызываю один раз и работает отлично. Но при каждом следующем вызове массив $result содержит в себе прошлые значения (я так понимаю это из-за static $result[]). Как можно очистить $result после выполнения функции textGenerator? Пробовал unset($result), $result=null, убирать static, но тогда перестает работать. Похожий вопрос нагуглил [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812953/how-do-you-clear-a-static-variable-in-php-after-recursion-is-finished), но там слегка другой случай.

```
function textGenerator($text) {
   static $result;
   if (preg_match("/^(.*)\{([^\{\}]+)\}(.*)$/isU", $text, $matches)){
      $p = explode('|', $matches[2]);
      foreach ($p as $comb)
         textGenerator($matches[1].$comb.$matches[3]);
      }
   else {
      $result[] = $text;
      return 0;
      }
   return array_values(array_unique($result));
   }
$text1 = '{1|2|3}';
$text2 = '{4|5|6}';
$text3 = '{7|8|9}';
echo count(textGenerator ($text1))."<br><br>"; // выводит 3, все ок
echo count(textGenerator ($text2))."<br><br>"; // выводит 6, а не 3
echo count(textGenerator ($text3))."<br><br>"; // выводит 9, а не 3
```

Comment: какой результат функции должен быть?

Comment: @Naumov в комментах в коде написано

Comment: @teran Зачем мне `count` и так понятно что там 3 должно быть, я  спрашиваю что должно в этих массивах быть

Comment: @Naumov пардоньте, я на `return 0` в функции глянул случайно, на `count` и внимание не обратил. Вообще несколько странный ход, возвращать разные типы результата

Comment: я честно сказать вообще не понял зачем тут рекурсия, вроде выходит что для входной строки `qwe{1|2|3}asd` просто генерится набор строк `qwe1asd`, `qwe2asd` и `qwe3asd`.

Comment: а не, для `qwe{1{x|y}|2}asd` будет 3 строки сгенерировано `1x,1y,2`

Comment: Вам вообще нужна статичная переменная? Вы же можете просто объединять массив с возвращаемыми значениями.

Comment: @etki он же _нашел функцию в интернете_, а не сам написал, поэтому видимо нужна :)

Comment: @etki да вот пытался переделать функции без static, но мозгов не хватило)

Comment: `если (задача делится на подзадачи) { объединить(разбить на подзадачи) } иначе { вернуть результат }`. Все предельно просто.

Comment: @etki спасибо вам за идею! teran написал готовый код, но я постарался в нем разобраться, оказалось не так уж и сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы, наверное, пробовали очищать массив не при выходе из рекурсии, а при входе из функции.
В принципе можно пойти двумя путями:

Первый - аналогично переменной `$result` использовать статичную переменную, отвечающую за подсчет глубины рекурсии, и очищать `$result`, когда глубина равна `0`:

```
function textGenerator($text) {
   static $result;

    static $deep = 0;
    if(!$deep) $result= [];
    $deep++;

    if (preg_match("/^(.*)\{([^\{\}]+)\}(.*)$/isU", $text, $matches)){
        $p = explode('|', $matches[2]);
        foreach ($p as $comb){
           textGenerator($matches[1].$comb.$matches[3]);
        }
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $text;
    }

    $deep--;
    return array_values(array_unique($result));
}
```

второй вариант - изменить сигнатуру функции, добавив туда параметр, который будет отвечать за очистку. Чтобы код вызова функций не менять, значение параметра по умолчанию - `true`.

```
function textGenerator($text, $clean = true) {
    static $result;

    if($clean) $result = [];

    if (preg_match("/^(.*)\{([^\{\}]+)\}(.*)$/isU", $text, $matches)){
        $p = explode('|', $matches[2]);
        foreach ($p as $comb)
            textGenerator($matches[1].$comb.$matches[3], false);
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $text;
    }
    return array_values(array_unique($result));
}
```

рекурсивный вызов внутри при этом происходит с параметром `false`.

В целом второй вариант, пожалуй и нагляднее и проще в реализации.

---

*раз уж написал ответ, то дополню по его вариантом без `static` переменной, согласно комментарию @etki к вопросу:*

```
function textGenerator($text) {
    $result = [];

    if (preg_match("/^(.*)\{([^\{\}]+)\}(.*)$/isU", $text, $matches)){
        $p = explode('|', $matches[2]);
        foreach ($p as $comb)
            $result = array_merge($result, textGenerator($matches[1].$comb.$matches[3]));
    }
    else {
        return  [$text];
    }
    return array_values(array_unique($result));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, @teran! оба варианта работают отлично)

Comment: @ИвановСергей добавил и третий вариант ;)

Comment: вижу, объединение массива выглядит несложно, только вот return [$text] не смог понять. Если preg_match вернул false, то зачем мы возвращаем $text, а не result и почему в квадратных скобках? Если несложно поясните пожалуйста)

Comment: @ИвановСергей нельзя в одном месте вернуть строку, а в другом массив. `array_merge` на вход принимает текущий массив и то, что вернулось из рекурсии. Поэтому из рекурсии всегда надо тоже возвращать массив, даже если там одна строка, как в `[$text]`, где `[...]` (скобки) это сокращенная запись определения массива, появившаяся где-то в пхп 5.6 (аналог `array($text)`)

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: P.S Почему-то 3 вариант выполняется в разы быстрее, чем остальные. Например если на вход textGenerator подавать строчку с 3 сотнями вариантов, то 1 и 2 функции (без static) выполняются за 0,13 секунд, а третья функция за 0,01 с. Хотя может я неправильно проверял (через microtime), слишком уж большая разница